# Parse JavaScript href with Python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Been having a lot of trouble with this... new to Python so sorry if I just don't know the proper search terms to find the info myself.  I'm not even positive it's because of the JS but that's the best idea I've got.

Here's the section of HTML I'm parsing:

```
...
<div class="promotion">
    <div class="address">
        <a href="javascript:PropDetail2('57795471:MRMLS')" title="View property detail for 5203 Alhama Drive">5203 Alhama Drive</a>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

...and the Python I'm using to do it (this version is the closest I've gotten to success):

```
homeFinderSoup = BeautifulSoup(open("homeFinderHTML.html"), "html5lib")
addressClass = homeFinderSoup.find_all('div', 'address')
for row in addressClass:
    print row.get('href')
```

...which returns

```
None
None
None
```

Comment: Without digging into the docs or anything, it looks like your code is iterating through the all the divs with class address and looking for an href property, which they don't have. You'll need to get all the anchor tags inside those divs and look for the href property of THOSE to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Had been having trouble navigating the tree and the lists have been throwing me off.  Set me the right direction though, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Create soup from the html. (Here I am assuming that you have already read the file into
# the variable "html" as a string).
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
# Find all divs with class="address"
address_class = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "address"})
# Loop over the results
for row in address_class:
  # Each result has one <a> tag, and we need to get the href property from it.
  print row.find('a').get('href')
```

Comment: That works, excellent, thank you.  Had been trying .find_all() before, doesn't work.